# How to sample along with another dataloader in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, dataloader, pytorch-lightning

Assume I have train/valid/test dataset with `batch_size` and `shuffle`ed as normal.

When I do train/valid/test, I want to sample a certain number (called `memory_size`) of new samples from the entire dataset for each sample.

For example, I set `batch_size` as `256`, let dataset shuffled, and `memory_size` as `80`.
In every `forward` step, not only use each sample from dataset, but sample data from **entire** original dataset which size is `memory_size` and I want to use it inside `forward`. Let new samples as *Memory* (Yeah, I want to adopt idea from [Memory Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1410.3916)). Memory can be **overlapped** between each sample in train set.

I'm using PyTorch and PyTorch-Lightning. Can I create new memory `dataloader` per each `train_dataloader`, `val_dataloader`, and `test_dataloader` then load it with original dataloader? or is there a better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Do you mean kfold crossvalidation?

Comment: I thought it was not, but eventually it is similar idea. I didn't implement proposed idea, but creating another memory dataset and sampling from it would solve this issue.